# Tinymce-rails proper tinymce.yml configuration for second toolbar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce-4

Works perfectly with only a single toolbar, but when I try to use the toolbar config pattern from the documentation in the yaml file in a Rails 4.2, the editor disappears completely.  Here is my yaml file, what I am doing wrong?

```
menubar: false
paste_merge_formats: true
paste_retain_style_properties: all
toolbar:
  - formatselect | fontselect | fontsizeselect | bold | italic | underline | strikethrough | alignleft | aligncenter | alignjustify | alignright
toolbar2:
  - bullist | numlist | outdent | indent | blockquote | forecolor | backcolor | undo | redo | link | unlink | preview | hr | searchreplace
plugins:
  - link
  - paste
  - importcss
  - autolink
  - lists
  - wordcount
  - colorpicker
  - hr
  - preview
  - searchreplace
  - textcolor
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly and you want the items in toolbar2 to appear as formatting options then you should simply remove the **toolbar2** declaration and you will get the toolbar2 formatting options in the menu.
Like this:

```
toolbar:
  - formatselect | fontselect | fontsizeselect | bold | italic | underline | strikethrough | alignleft | aligncenter | alignjustify | alignright
  - bullist | numlist | outdent | indent | blockquote | forecolor | backcolor | undo | redo | link | unlink | preview | hr | searchreplace
plugins:
        ...
```